# Object-Oriented design - how important is encapsulation when there're lots of data-fields in one class?

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

I've a question regarding encapsulation:

Is it recommended to use encapsulation when a class has lots of data-fields?

Using the following class as an example:

```
abstract public class Character {
    private String name;
    private String characterClass;
    private int level;
    private int hitDice;

    private int strength;
    private int constitution;
    private int dexterity;
    private int intelligence;
    private int wisdom;
    private int charisma;

    private int hp;
    private int currentHp;
    private int armorClass;
    private int BaseAttackBonus;

    private long xp;
    private double gp;

    private Inventory inventory;
    private double carriedWeight;

    private Equipment equipment;

    protected Character(String name) {

        setName(name);
        setCharacterClass("Class");
        setLevel(1);
        setHitDice(0);

        setStrength(10);
        setConstitution(10);
        setDexterity(10);
        setIntelligence(10);
        setWisdom(10);
        setCharisma(10);

        setHp((int) getLevel() * (getHitDice() + getModifier(getConstitution())));
        setCurrentHp(getHp());
        setArmorClass(10 + getModifier(getDexterity()));
        setBaseAttackBonus(0);

        inventory = new Inventory();
        setCarriedWeight(0);

        equipment = new Equipment();

        setXp(0);
        setGp(20);

    }

    protected Character(String name, int lvl) {

        setName(name);
        setCharacterClass("Class");
        setLevel(lvl);
        setHitDice(0);

        setStrength(10);
        setConstitution(10);
        setDexterity(10);
        setIntelligence(10);
        setWisdom(10);
        setCharisma(10);

        setHp((int) getLevel() * (getHitDice() + getModifier(getConstitution())));
        setCurrentHp(getHp());
        setArmorClass(10 + getModifier(getDexterity()));
        setBaseAttackBonus(0);

        inventory = new Inventory();
        setCarriedWeight(0);

        equipment = new Equipment();

        setXp(1000 * (getLevel() - 1));
        setGp(getLevel() * 20);

    }

    void displayCharacter() throws IOException {
        System.out.print("\n\n");
        System.out.println("Name: " + getName());
        System.out.println("Class: " + getCharacterClass());
        System.out.println("Level: " + getLevel());
        System.out.println("HP: " + getHp());
        System.out.println("Current HP: " + getCurrentHp());
        System.out.println("Armor Class: " + getArmorClass());
        System.out.println("Base Attack Bonus : +" + getBaseAttackBonus());

        System.out.println("***************");
        System.out.println("Attributes: ");
        System.out.println("Strength: " + getStrength());
        System.out.println("Constitution: " + getConstitution());
        System.out.println("Dexterity: " + getDexterity());
        System.out.println("Intelligence: " + getIntelligence());
        System.out.println("Wisdom: " + getWisdom());
        System.out.println("Charisma: " + getCharisma());
        System.out.println("***************");
        equipment.showEquipment();
        inventory.showInventory();
        System.out.println("Carried weight: " + getCarriedWeight());

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("XP: " + getXp());
        System.out.println("Gold: " + getGp());
        System.out.println("");

    }

    public int getModifier(int number) {
        int mod = (int) ((number - 10) / 2);
        return mod;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCharacterClass() {
        return characterClass;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public int getHitDice() {
        return hitDice;
    }

    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    public int getConstitution() {
        return constitution;
    }

    public int getDexterity() {
        return dexterity;
    }

    public int getIntelligence() {
        return intelligence;
    }

    public int getWisdom() {
        return wisdom;
    }

    public int getCharisma() {
        return charisma;
    }

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }

    public int getCurrentHp() {
        return currentHp;
    }

    public int getArmorClass() {
        return armorClass;
    }

    public int getBaseAttackBonus() {
        return BaseAttackBonus;
    }

    public Equipment getEquipment() {
        return equipment;
    }

    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public double getCarriedWeight() {
        return carriedWeight;
    }

    public long getXp() {
        return xp;
    }

    public double getGp() {
        return gp;
    }

    protected void setName(String Name) {
        name = Name;
    }

    protected void setCharacterClass(String characterClass) {
        this.characterClass = characterClass;
    }

    protected void setLevel(int lvl) {
        level = lvl;
    }

    protected void setHitDice(int hd) {
        hitDice = hd;
    }

    protected void setStrength(int str) {
        strength = str;
    }

    protected void setConstitution(int con) {
        constitution = con;
    }

    protected void setDexterity(int dex) {
        dexterity = dex;
    }

    protected void setIntelligence(int intel) {
        intelligence = intel;
    }

    protected void setWisdom(int wis) {
        wisdom = wis;
    }

    protected void setCharisma(int cha) {
        charisma = cha;
    }

    protected void setHp(int hitPoints) {
        hp = hitPoints;
    }

    protected void setCurrentHp(int curHp) {
        currentHp = curHp;
    }

    protected void setArmorClass(int ac) {
        armorClass = ac;
    }

    protected void setBaseAttackBonus(int bab) {
        BaseAttackBonus = bab;
    }

    protected void setXp(int XP) {
        xp = XP;
    }

    protected void setGp(double GP) {
        gp = GP;
    }

    protected void setCarriedWeight(double weight) {
        carriedWeight = weight;
    }

    public void attack(Character target) {

        try {
            ((Weapon) getEquipment().getPrimaryHand()).attack(this, target);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            getEquipment().equipPrimaryHand(
                    MeleeWeapon.meleeWeaponList.get(0)); /* equip fist weapon */
            ((Weapon) getEquipment().getPrimaryHand()).attack(this, target);

            if (target.getCurrentHp() <= 0) {
                System.out.println(target.getName() + " is down !");
            }
        }
    }

    public void equip() {
        getInventory().equip(this);
    }

    public void addToInventory(Item newItem) {
        getInventory().addToInventory(this, newItem);
    }

}
```

Would storing most of the data-fields in different classes, such as `strength` and `constitution` in a `Stats` class, be considered as a better design?

Comment: I mean it looks quite good from what you have. This is more of a code review question though i believe.

Comment: "lots of data-fields" is not the criteria. It's: are all those datafields there for the same purpose: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: "is it recommended to use encapsulation when a class has lots of data-fields"  Where did you find this? A few or a lot of fields are NOT the factor to use encapsulation. Check your OOP.

Comment: Just a correction, you wouldnt have to change your setters to ` setStrength(Character character, Strength Str) ` but it would be something like `char.getStats().setStrength(12)`

Comment: @bruno_cw , true. I edited that part in the question. But the question remains as it was - should I add a Stats class or not ?

Comment: @NathanHughes , but all these fields depicts the state of a character. If I need all the stats for a character, then how can I totally separate it from Character class ?

Comment: It depends, will every monster have the same stats? it could be good because of reuse

Comment: @bruno_cw, Character is an abstract class that includes all the common data-fields (Mage class also has spellbook field of Spellbook class). As for now, each subclass of Character produce same stats, though it might change in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're referring to [decomposition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_(computer_science)) - the act of breaking large systems down into smaller, easier to understand parts.

To properly decompose your code, you must focus on [cohesion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)): How many things does your class represent? How well do they "stick" together?

Your class currently represents quite a few things:

1. Character identity info, such as `name`
2. Skill Tracker, such as `constition`
3. Experience Tracker
4. Inventory
5. Personal Scale

Your 1 class represents multiple entities; it has low cohesion.

---

So to answer your question, **yes, moving stat related fields to a stat class would be a good thing**. But it's not just the fields you should move, it's the entire responsibility. This means if you have a `resetStats()` method, it too would go to the `Stat` class.

Decomposition helps further encapsulation if the members being moved are `private`, since it further hides info. But decomposition is it's own subject.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, I meant to decomposition, I'm new to the OO world :)

Comment: So Stats class should include level, strength, armorClass etc ? Experience points (xp), and gold (gp) aren't stats, should I also include them in stats class ?

Comment: @Niminim It would definitely contain `strength`, since that is a stat. I'm not sure what `armorClass` is, so that would really depend on it's context. To me, it sounds like equipment information. `gold` sounds like an item, and `xp` really depends on how you handle things. You may decompose each stat into it's own type, such as `FireMaking`, which has all the details for that skill

Comment: armorClass is how hard is it to hit you ( a combination of dexterity (stat) and the armor the character is equipped with (equipment). Some additions like "abilities" might have a role here in the future (like evasive abilities), but not for now)

Comment: Yeah, gold is definitely belongs to inventory. I think I understand this thought process.

Comment: armor class sounds like a method to me. You could do `public getAC() { return this.baseDefense + this.getShied().getDefense() }` or something like that, if it needs constant recalculation (every time your char equips / unequips armor) it doesnt make sense to store its value, just make a getter function returning the calculation

Comment: @Niminim Sounds more like a `Bonus` than an actual `Stat`, but it really all depends on how it'll be used in your game. If it's not actually a bonus, as in it doesn't add onto your equipment's defence, rather than has its own specific purpose, then it may be wise to keep it in `Stats`. But like I said, it all depends on how it'll be used in your game (What may happen thatll require you to modify that code. Look further into SRP)

Comment: @bruno_cw , I already have that method in Equipment class. When a character is equipped with an armor by using equipBodyArmor method then there's a calculation (setArmorClass( 10 + ..... +.....).

Comment: @Niminim If that method is in your equipment class, maybe its best to put the `armorClass` there aswell

Comment: Yeah, just what I thought while looking at Character class code. Character class was the first class I created while Equipment was the last one :)

Comment: @VinceEmigh I made some changes in the whole code  and it makes things more cohesive. thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

Objects have behavior. State within the object is there to support that behavior. Separating out a bunch of state, simply as a container of state, rather than a distinct object with their own specific behaviors, doesn't make a lot of sense in the big picture of things.